# PySpark-How to find out the top n most frequently occurring value in an array column?

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For the sample data below, wondering how I can find out the most frequently occurring value in the column `colour`. The data type of `colour` is WrappedArray. There could be n number of elements in the array. In this example the colour should be yellow, followed by blue which appeared twice. Many thanks for your help.

```
Name   Colour 
 A      ('blue','yellow')
 B      ('pink', 'yellow')
 C      ('green', 'black')
 D      ('yellow','orange','blue')
```

Comment: note - `WrappedArray` is only available in spark-scala. are you working on scala and looking for ideas/solutions using that?

Comment: to samkart's point, if you're using `spark-scala`, you can edit the tags accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) the colour column and then simply run groupBy and count to get what you need.

```
df \
.select(explode('colour').alias('colour')) \
.groupBy('colour') \
.count() \
.orderBy(col('count').desc())
```